# Solve polynomials equations $e^{2x}+4e^x+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a problem to solve this polynomials equation,
$e^{2x} + 4e^x+2=0$
roots of the equation are $x_1$ and $x_2$
now $x_1+x_2=$?

I know that if equation is like $ax^2+ bx+c=0$
and roots are $x_1$ and $x_2$ then $x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $x_1\cdot x_2= \frac{c}{a}$
but I don't know what happens if x is in power.

Comment: Let $e^x=y$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $y=e^x$, $y_1=e^{x_1}$ and $y_2=e^{x_2}$. Then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the roots of $y^2+4y+2=0$.

So $y_1y_2=2$ and hence

$$e^{x_1}e^{x_2}=2$$

Therefore, $e^{x_1+x_2}=2$.

$$x_1+x_2=\ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may set
$$
X=e^x
$$ then one is led to consider the quadratic equation
$$
X^2+4X+2=0.
$$